# How to increase score for documents matching multiple words in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

When I am searching for `dubai tour` , I am getting these results:

1. Dubai
2. iVenture Dubai Select Pass
3. Big Bus Dubai: Night Tour
4. Big Bus Dubai: Hop-On, Hop-Off Bus Tour
5. City Sightseeing Dubai: Hop-On, Hop-Off Bus Tour
6. At-The-Top Burj Khalifa: 124th & 125th Floor Ticket - Last Minute Availability & Instant Confirmation!

I am getting it because I am sorting the results on the basis of a field that is present in my document `totalScore` which may be more for `iVenture Dubai Select Pass` document. But in `iVenture Dubai Select Pass` only `dubai` is present but for other results like `Big Bus Dubai: Night Tour` both `dubai` and `tour` are present.
So obviously document having both `dubai` and `tour` should be coming first, but It's not happening.

```
   must: [
           {
          multi_match: {
            query: keyword,
            fields: ['servicename_regionname'],
              },
           },
         ],
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: As you are applying sort on `totalScore` field it is obvious that it will return document which have `totalScore` values is high.

Comment: but as you see a document matching both `dubai and tour`  is more relevant that a document matching just `dubai` @SagarPatel

Comment: then you need to remove sort from your query or you need to add multi-sort. first sort on ` _score` and second sort on `totalScore`